# If a value in column A is unique in column A, return 0, else return 1, in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to see how many duplicate values there are in a column.

I would like code on Excel for:

*If a value in column `A`, is unique in the whole of column `A`, then return `0`, otherwise return `1`*

Here a sample (input and expected output):

| Input | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |

Please share syntax

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COUNTIF` for that for example:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A6,A2:A6)>1,1,0)
```

[image]

If you want to know how many duplicates you have, just:

```
=COUNTA(A2:A6) - COUNTA(UNIQUE(A2:A6)) -> 1
```